# Accessing Inner ng-repeat Objects to fit into table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, authentication

I am Fetching this data from Backend Calls in JSON Format. I am facing a lot of issues in creating a data structure to handle this data in front page, take response from it and send it back to backend.

```
[


{
    "name": "dataAccess",
    "description": null,
    "type": null,
    "permission": [
      {
        "name": "delete",
        "description": null,
        "enabled": false
      },
      {
        "name": "edit",
        "description": null,
        "enabled": false
      },
      {
        "name": "export",
        "description": null,
        "enabled": false
      },
      {
        "name": "write",
        "description": null,
        "enabled": false
      },
      {
        "name": "read",
        "description": null,
        "enabled": false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "entity",
    "description": null,
    "type": null,
    "permission": [
      {
        "name": "export",
        "description": null,
        "enabled": false
      },
      {
        "name": "edit",
        "description": null,
        "enabled": false
      },
      {
        "name": "write",
        "description": null,
        "enabled": false
      },
      {
        "name": "read",
        "description": null,
        "enabled": false
      },
      {
        "name": "delete",
        "description": null,
        "enabled": false
      }
    ]

  }
]
```

There are Object names, Permission Names and Object Related Permissions. The Outer Loop name specifies the object name (Eg: Dataaccess) and the inner loop (permission) specifies the permission this Dataaccess object has, (i.e. delete,read etc). 
These Permissions are not static and may be added in to SQL any time, hence I had to create an array.

The following is what I want in my HTML page.

The table's row will be permission Name, and columns will map these permissions to object.

```
 ModuleName      Read        Edit      Delete       Export      write
 dataAccess    CheckBox  Checkbox    ChecckBox    CheckBox    CheckBox
 Entity        CheckBox  Checkbox    ChecckBox    CheckBox    CheckBox
```

The value of these checkboxes are the values these permissions have, i.e. if false, the checkbox for that particular object permission will be unchcked and vice-versa.

User can edit this page uncheck the checked boxes and I have to return the same JSON array with updated values.

I tried using ng-repeat within ng-repeat in html, but that results in two head, because I have two rows now. They will increase as the rows increase which I don't want.

I have tried creating custom filter, directive but I am not able to place the permissions correctly. They always mismatch in order. And if I am even able to do that, I am unable to fetch the updated value.

Comment: your permission are not coming in a the same order.

Comment: Yes that is the issue, permisions are same, but when I send it from backend, they will not be in same order>
Also, the number of permissions is not known, it can increase or decrease. Hence it is in array , other wise it would have in array objects.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found it out myself !!!

Here is what I did in my Controller, I rearranged the sequence of data in order.

```
angular.forEach(data,function(maindata,mainkey){

                $scope.PermissionNames=[];  
                maindata.permission.sort(function(a, b){
                     var nameA=a.name.toLowerCase(), nameB=b.name.toLowerCase()
                     if (nameA < nameB) //sort string ascending
                      return -1 
                     if (nameA > nameB)
                      return 1
                     return 0 //default return value (no sorting)
                    });

                $scope.ObjectPermissions.push({name:maindata.name,permission:maindata.permission}); // Main Data

                angular.forEach(maindata.permission,function(childData,childKey){
                    $scope.PermissionNames.push({name:childData.name});

                });

                $scope.PermissionNames.sort(function(a, b){
                 var nameA=a.name.toLowerCase(), nameB=b.name.toLowerCase()
                 if (nameA < nameB) //sort string ascending
                  return -1 
                 if (nameA > nameB)
                  return 1
                 return 0 //default return value (no sorting)
                });

            });
```

So they will always be sorted and then I Used it like this in HTML\

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-bordered">
        <thead >
        <tr>
            <th>Module</th>
            <th ng-repeat="maindata in PermissionNames">{{maindata.name}}</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="Object in ObjectPermissions ">
            <td >{{Object.name}}</td>
            <td ng-repeat="permissionValue in Object.permission" >

                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="permissionValue.enabled"  
                            ng-checked="permissionValue.enabled"
                            ng-click="checkValue($parent.$index,$index,permissionValue.enabled)">

            </td>

        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

How this helps anybody, who face similar Issue